# Describing contrary idiom usage

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

I periodically get emails inviting me to a "free" lunch for the purpose of hearing a sales pitch.  Multiple times these invitations have included some quip such as "See?  There *is* such thing as a free lunch!".

But the phrase "[There's no such thing as a free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)" describes, almost literally, the advertisement: the lunch is not free because I have to pay the rather steep price of hearing a high-pressure sales pitch.

The author of such quips appears ignorant of their own ironic misuse of the idiom.  Is there a name for this type of situation?

CLARIFICATION:

The question is not whether or not advertisers try to deceive.  I'm asking if there is a phrase which describes "ironic misuse of an idiom".

Comment: You're just using a different definition of "free" than the salesperson. He's defining "free" as in "doesn't cost you money", and you're using "doesn't cost you anything".

Comment: @Marthaª But the idiom is specifically pointing out that "free" doesn't always mean money, you pay one way or another--in this case by having to sit and listen.

Comment: It's called sales talk. It was invented by Lewis Carroll in *Through the Looking-Glass*.

Comment: @andy256, is your point that we shouldn't analyze sales talk here?  It was just an example, perhaps I should find another.

Comment: It's virtually a truism that [every proverb has an opposite proverb](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=every+proverb+has+opposite+proverb&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). Depending on your perspective, you can either say one's right & the other wrong (or vice-versa! :) or that they're both just "context-specific". I therefore think this question is POB or peeve. But then again I think [the best things in life are free](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/best+things+in+life+are+free), so what do I know?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've tried to clarify the question a little better.

Comment: @Codie: It's not clear to me whether you can properly classify a usage as "ironic" just because in *your* opinion there's a [*contrast between apparent and intended meaning*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irony). That dictionary definition says it has to be ***deliberate***, which sounds right to me in most contexts. If you think you've got enough people on your side regarding any given saying/adage/rule you think doesn't stand up, you could call it *discredited*, I suppose. I seriously doubt there will be a specific word for incorrect (or incorrectly *used*) utterances like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I debated using "ironic", but the whole point is that I don't know how to properly describe it.  I like bib's "oxymoronic irony", but I suppose that still fails the "deliberate" criterion.

Comment: I don't think this is [ironic](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-is-irony-with-examples/).

Comment: @Susan: You must surely accept that words mean *what we think they mean **now***, not what some long-dead person once defined them to mean. So assuming they have a reasonably representative "user base", I don't see [how we can disagree with whatever this site](http://www.isitironic.com/) says is either "ironic" or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - that's an interesting website, thanks. It does underscore the misuse of the word "ironic". Now, this, to me, is ironic: *...if you have a phobia of long words, and you have to tell people that you have Hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia?"*

Comment: @Susan: I'm actually ambivalent over that one. Is it truly ironic that *the technical name for "fear of long words" is a very long word itself?* It seems a bit akin to saying *you never know what you've got 'til it's gone* is ironic. What about *that the people who complain most are the ones who do least?* Personally, I think there's a case for saying it's ironic that OP perceives "irony" (or at least, the *misuse* thereof) in a context where none was intended (so it wasn't really "[mis]used"), and he was not deceived (so he understood the intended meaning).

Answer (score 1):

It is, perhaps, **oxymoronic irony**

> [oxymoron](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oxymoron): A rhetorical figure in which incongruous or contradictory terms are combined
>
> [irony](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irony): incongruity between what is expected to be and what actually is, or a situation or result showing such incongruity

While the words themselves may not be contradictory, the very perception of the words is a contradiction of their meaning. Just hearing the hawker say *there **is** a free lunch* costs you dearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with *asinine allusion*

allusion per mw:

> the act of making an indirect reference to something :  the act of alluding to something

asinine:

> 1. extremely or utterly foolish  2. :  of, relating to, or resembling an ass

If you find the better, a *witty allusion*

Comment: I've never really thought that asses were particularly foolish.